# Ubuntu 14.04 can't find Network Configuration during boot

Tags: 14.04, network-manager

Each time I boot Ubuntu can't find the Network Configuration.  It takes an extra 2 minutes to boot and then finds it about 3 minutes after logging in.  Is there a way to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: This may be a symptom of an error in your `/etc/networking/interfaces`. Please edit your question with the contents of this file.